# Passing parameters by URL in JSF

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to go to page by selecting data table row. Using ajax event have some problems.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "/views/questionnaires/viewDetails.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&questionnaireId=" + 1);
```

But also i need to pass parameter to target page bean.

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.questionnaireId}")
private Long questionnaireId;
```

And it's not working. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that needs to be done is that you need to include `includeViewParams=true` in that URL for the parameter to survive the redirect. So you'll have:

```
  navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "/views/questionnaires/viewDetails.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&questionnaireId=" + 1);
```

Another concern might be the scope of the target bean. Per JSF spec, `@ViewScoped` beans are not valid targets for `#param` bean injection